# Python IRC Find status messages

Tags: python, irc, twitch

**Made for Twitch chat**
I would like to search the irc chat for a certain message. The problem with my current code is that the message is actually a status and I have no clue on how to detect the status.

Code:

```
while True:
try:
    data = data+con.recv(1024)
    data_split = re.split(r"[~\r\n]+", data)
    data = data_split.pop()

    for line in data_split:
        print(line)
        line = str.rstrip(line)
        line = str.split(line)


        if len(line) >= 1:
            if line[0] == 'PING':
                send_pong(con, line[1])

            if line[1] == 'PRIVMSG':
                sender = get_sender(line[0])
                message = get_message(line)
                channel = line[2]
                print(sender + ": " + message)

                if (re.match(':jtv MODE \w* +o \w*', message)):
                    mods.append(channel)
                    mods[channel].append(msg[4])
```

The original status looks like this:
:jtv MODE #CHAN +o/-o #nick

I would also like to use the mods array in another file (if that is possible) to check if they are a mod or not. Otherwise I can write it to a .txt file.

Comment: Please provide more code. And `\w*` is a wrong thing to match an IRC nick. (matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` only, never seen a ^ in nick, say?)

Comment: Twitch seems to block any special characters in usernames. (As far as I've seen), also what code would you need?

Comment: I'd instead look for everything separated by spaces/whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Antti Haapala. Found a solution for my structure:

```
 message = ' '.join(line)
 x = re.findall('^:jtv MODE (.*?) \+o (.*)$', message)
 if (len(x) > 0):
     #print('DEBUG: Regex')
     channel = x[0][0] 
     if (channel not in mods):
         mods[channel] = []
         list = mods.get(channel)
         list.append(x[0][1])
         print(mods)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex for this, instead checking the parts:

```
parts = message.split()
if len(parts) == 5 and parts[:2] == [':jtv', 'MODE']:
    # it is a mode change
    channel, mode, nick = parts[2:5]
    if mode == '-o':
        # ...
```